# How do you refer to a each individual event in a list?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that will spit out a difference response depending on which 'event' is chosen in a list i've created; it will be selected using random.choice() but I don't know how to refer to each individual thing that's part of the list? I don't know how to explain this v well i'm sorry.

here is my code so far:

```
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    name = ctx.author.display_name

    high = random.randrange(30, 50)
    low = random.randrange(0)

    earnings = random.choice(str([f'{example 1}', f'{example 2}'])

    if earnings == [0]: # i want to refer to the first 'thing' in the list here
        await ctx.send(f"{earnings}\ncongratulations you have earned {low} coins")
    if earnings == [1]: # and the second 'thing' here
        await ctx.send(f"{earnings}\ncongratulations you have earned {top} coints")
```

Comment: give each event a unique string `name`, then you can do: `if earnings.name == 'event_1':` and so on

Comment: if i were to do that, how would i use random.choice() ?

Answer (score 0):

You may create the list and use `random.choice(YourList)`, so you may refer to YourList later

```
possibilities = [example1, example2]
earnings = random.choice(possibilities)

if earnings == possibilities[0]:
    await ctx.send(f"{earnings}\ncongratulations you have earned {low} coins")
elif earnings == possibilities[1]: 
    await ctx.send(f"{earnings}\ncongratulations you have earned {top} coints")
```

Comment: I noticed that you tried to convert the list elements into string `earnings = random.choice(str([f'{example 1}', f'{example 2}'])` if you need that, you can use map() function `possibilities = list(map(str, possibilities))` this means that all elements in possibilities list now are string